# tkz-euclide's \tkzDrawTriangle undefined with an up to date TL 2016

Tags: tkz-euclide

According to the `tkz-euclide`'s documentation, the following MnWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDrawTriangle(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is supposed to compile nicely (and, IIRC, it used to be the case) but, with an up to date TL 2016, the following error is thrown:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \tkzDrawTriangle
                     (A,B)
```

Here is my File List:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-euclide.sty    2011/06/01 1.16 c for plots 2d 
tkz-base.sty    2011/06/01 1.16 c tkz-base
    etex.sty    2016/08/01 v2.7 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
numprint.sty    2012/08/20 v1.39 Print numbers (HH)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
tkz-tools-utilities.tex
tkz-tools-arith.tex
tkz-tools-base.tex
tkz-tools-misc.tex
tkz-tools-math.tex
tkz-obj-points.tex
tkz-obj-segments.tex
tkz-obj-marks.tex
tkz-tools-intersections.tex
tkz-tools-transformations.tex
tkz-obj-lines.tex
tkz-lib-symbols.tex
tkz-obj-circles.tex
tkz-obj-addpoints.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Ha, got it: `tkz-euclide.sty` consists mainly of `\input` of some files, such as `tkz-tools-intersections.tex` or `tkz-obj-lines.tex`, but is missing `tkz-obj-polygons.tex` which defines  `\tkzDrawTriangle`. I'll let know `tkz-euclide.sty's author.

Comment: Please consider converting your comment to an answer and including the author's response, when you get it. (Unless the author answers here, of course.) Otherwise, this will just sit 'unanswered' ;).

Comment: @cfr For sure, I'll do it when I'll have an answer from the author :) But I'll wait for it because I discover other bugs of the same kind: for `\tkzMarkRightAngle` you need to add `tkz-obj-angles.tex`, for `\tkzMarkAngle` you need to add `tkz-obj-arcs.tex`, etc.

Comment: Given the answer below, it seems likely this is modular by design. Just as you need `\usetikzlibrary{<something>}` to use various different things in regular Ti*k*Z. For large packages, this is a very common framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
\usetkzobj{all}
```

and this works just fine.

Comment: Indeed but a bug of `tkz-euclide` anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I don't know, could be by design that you have to load some or all `tkz` "objects", or it could be a mistake. I'd ask Alain Matthes about it, as you have planned to do.

Comment: As said by cfr, that's indeed seems to be by design that `\usetkzobj{...}` has to be added.